# My database data is not showing on my xaml page in xamarin

Tags: c#, sqlite, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

i'm pretty new to xamarin, i just started working with sqlite databases using "Beginning Mobile Development with Xamarin
by Jesse Liberty" on pluralsight. i am pretty sure my code is fine , it saves to my database and i have checked this using a database brower, so i know the data is in there. but when i go to my list view on my app, the data does not show.

This is my database code

```
using System;
using SQLite;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;


namespace Todo
{
    public class TodoDataBase
    {
        private SQLiteConnection database;

        static object locker = new object();

        public TodoDataBase ()
        {
            database = DependencyService.Get<ISQLite>().GetConnection();
            database.CreateTable<TodoItem> ();

        }

        public TodoItem GetToDo(int id)
        {
            lock (locker) 
            {
                return database.Table<TodoItem> ().Where (c => c.Id == id).FirstOrDefault ();
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<TodoItem> GetToDos()
        {
            lock (locker) 
            {
                return (from c in database.Table<TodoItem>()
                    select c).ToList();
            }
        }

        public int SaveToDo(TodoItem todothing)
        {
            lock (locker)
            {               
                if (todothing.Id != 0) 
                {
                     database.Update (todothing);
                    return todothing.Id;
                } 
                else
                {
                    return database.Insert (todothing);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

This is my code behind for my page displaying the list view

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Todo
{
    public partial class ReviewPage : ContentPage
    {


        public ReviewPage ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
        }


        public void onSelected(object o, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
        {
            var selectedItem = e.Item as TodoItem;

            DisplayAlert ("You Selected", "Task " + selectedItem.TaskName, "Bye Bye");
        }


        public void onAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing ();
            TodoList.ItemsSource = App.Database.GetToDos ();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my xaml page

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage
     xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
     xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Todo;Assembly=Todo"
     x:Class="Todo.ReviewPage">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <local:DateTimeConverter x:Key = "dtConverter"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

        <StackLayout Padding = "15">
             <ListView x:Name="TodoList" ItemTapped="onSelected">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <ViewCell.View>
                                <StackLayout Padding="5" Spacing="2">
                                    <Label x:Name="TaskNameDisplay" Text="{Binding TaskName}" FontSize="12" TextColor="Red"/>
                                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <Label Text="Priority" FontSize="10"/>
                                            <Label Text="{Binding Priority}" FontSize="10"/>
                                            <Label Text="Due: " FontSize="12"/>
                                            <Label Text="{Binding DueDate, Converter = {StaticResource dtConverter}}" FontSize="10"/>
                                        </StackLayout>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell.View>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
             </ListView>
        </StackLayout>  
</ContentPage>
```

this is the code for the ViewModel of my main page where the data is being inserted 
using System;

```
namespace Todo
{
    public class CreatePageViewModel
    {
        public CreatePageViewModel ()
        {

        }

        public void AddTask(string todo,string priority, DateTime duedate, int hour,int minute, int second, int Updateid, bool isDeleted)
        {
            var newtodo = new TodoItem 
            {

                TaskName = todo,
                Priority = priority,
                Duedate = setDueDate (duedate, hour, minute, second),
                IsDeleted = isDeleted,
                Id = Updateid

            };

            App.Database.SaveToDo (newtodo);
        }

        private DateTime setDueDate( DateTime date, int hour,int minute, int second)
        {
            DateTime retVal = new DateTime (
                date.Year, date.Month, date.Day,hour,minute, second);
            return retVal;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please prefer to write down the code instead of capturing images, you might get downvoted for this, i suggest you to edit your question and add your code in text

Comment: Are you sure there is data in your db when GetTodos executes?  I see code to create the db, but nothing to insert any seed data.  Your code looks correct.  You might try inserting some test data when the db is created.

Comment: @CDrosos i have written down the code...

Comment: @Jason , yes i am sure the database is being populated. after running the app on my emulator and inserting data from there i checked the database using an sqlite data browser and i could see my data in the database file.

Comment: function GetToDos is the function for retrieving all data in the database

Comment: where and how anre you calling SaveToDo to add objects to the database?

Comment: Have you verified that GetToDos is returning data, either using the debugger or via a Console.Writeline?

Comment: @CDrosos saveTodo is being called in the ViewModel and i have verified that it works... the problem seems to be from the code returning the data in the database not from inserting the data....

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its a problem with the context. Check here for a very good [tutorial on how to use SQLite](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/792883/Using-Sqlite-in-a-Xamarin-Android-Application-Deve) as the tutorial says:

> Before we can invoke any database functionality, the SQLiteOpenHelper subclass we created above needs to know the context of the application in order for it to work. In our case, we need to set the application context to our subclass DataManagerHelper.

So first try to add on the ToDo class a way to set the Content and then set the Content on ReviewPage and try again